# plot dates on x-axis with gap of 6 months

Tags: matlab

I have a cell of shape 1 x 1358 which contains dates in a string format. Its daily data over approx 5 years.

I have a simple plot. On the x-axis I would like to have the dates not the number or number of observations. I only want the year and month shown and only want a label shown every 6 months.

How do I do this?

Below is what I have tried

```
ax1 = figure(1);
ax1.XTick = pdates;
datetick(ax1,'x','yy-mmm','keepticks');
```

Here is the error message

```
Error using datetick>parseinputs (line 325)
Incorrect arguments

Error in datetick (line 109)
[axh,nin,ax,dateform,keep_ticks,keep_limits] = parseinputs(varargin);

Error in plot_variables (line 27)
datetick(ax1,'x','yy-mmm','keepticks');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be

```
ax1 = gca;   %// obtain the current axis-handle
ax1.XTick = pdates;
datetick(ax1,'x','yy-mmm','keepticks');
```

Comment: just tried the above but get an error on the datetick line. Error using datetick>parseinputs (line 325)
Incorrect arguments

Error in datetick (line 109)
[axh,nin,ax,dateform,keep_ticks,keep_limits] = parseinputs(varargin);

Error in plot_variables (line 27)
    datetick(ax1, 'x', 'yy-mmm','keepticks');

Comment: i don't have the value for `pdates`. i tried without that line and didn't get any error. @mHelpMe